# Bed crashing into print head when levelling

Tags: bed-leveling, creality-ender-5

I have been printing okay for months, but, I had an overnight print failure for the first time; so turned off the printer. Restarted it, thought I would need to level the bed. Normally when I turn on the printer it will go to the X, Y, endstops then center on the bed; it did not do it this time...

And now when I do a bed leveling. Press leveling on the screen. the printer will go to the X and Y stops, the center and the bed will lower and comes up and the BL Touch will drop out, contact the bed and the bed goes back down, the bed comes back up and contacting the BLTouch again, and the bed will go back down. All is good so far. Then the bed comes back up again BUT does not stop and crashes into the print head. I have tried and tried for hours to sort this out but have failed.

Can anyone help whit this? I have asked on many forums without any success?
I have not changed anything, and have been printing for 7 plus months without an issue. I even have not changed anything, I have a video of the problem:

Comment: As a comment, I see you skipped a step. If this is the solution I'll post a proper answer. If you look at the following video, you will see that you need to manually press the homing button before you do the leveling. It is best to check that first.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zSOVAdKw4ss

Comment: Thank you ( hiome is normaly set first just not in this vid).
However, after looking at the video clip you posted the link for it did show me something  This was to open a print file and have a look at the Z Compensation setting. the setting in my last print was a staggering 25.34mm !!!! how and why i do not know. So i reset it to 00.00 and then cancelled the print and went back to doing the levelling and all when ok this time. I do not know how or why the Z compensation had changed it is normally around 1 .to1.05 ish. as i say i cannot find how or why it had changed
Thank you